# What's the best way to get a function return to wait until an asynchronous operation has finished?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Given the following prototype function:

```
Client.prototype.getLocalIp = function() {
    var rtc = new window.RTCPeerConnection({iceServers: []});
    rtc.createDataChannel('', {reliable: false});
    var that = this;

    rtc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            that.localIp = grep(event.candidate.candidate);
        }
    };

    rtc.createOffer(function (offer) {
        that.localIp = grep(offer.sdp);
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }, function (error) {
        console.warn('Fetching local IP failed', error);
    });

    var grep = function(sdpOrCandidate) {
        // Does lots of string processing stuff and returns a string
    }

    console.log("Returning from function");
    console.log(this.localIp);
}
```

How can I stop the function from returning until the `grep` function has finished doing its business and returned a value? Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/tjkxcL1j/

If you look in your browser console you should see that the `getLocalIp()` function is returning null first until the async stuff from `rtc.onicecandidate` and/or `rtc.createOffer` is finished.

Comment: You cannot *wait*, because js is single threaded. That is - when it does something - everything else is frozen. Instead - check "promises"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to accept a callback argument

```
Client.prototype.getLocalIp = function getLocalIp(done) {

  // ...
  rtc.createOffer(function (offer) {
    that.localIp = grep(offer.sdp);
    rtc.setLocalDescription(offer);

    // call the callback here
    done(null, that.localIp);
  },
  function (error) {
    console.warn('Fetching local IP failed', error);

    // call the callback with an error here
    done(error);
  });
};
```

Then you can use it like this

```
client.getLocalIp(function(err, ip){
  if (err) return console.error(err.message);
  console.log("client ip", ip);
});
```

However, as @zerkms mentions in a comment, this is only going to work if actually async operations are happening. Examples include accessing information over a network or accessing the disk.

Comment: Is there not another way to do it without using a callback every time? I don't want to have to use one every time I get property.

Comment: @ChrisWhite async doesn't happen without a callback. Sorry. JavaScript is not multithreaded.

Comment: @ChrisWhite, think it through in your head. How would your program proceed without waiting to get the IP. Say a function were to run that depends on the IP being in memory already, then what? How do you expect parallel operation without building explicit structure around it? At some point we need to be able to say, "ok A, B, and C are in place, now we can proceed to D."